# iphone: how to add text above and below the image in the scrollvew?

Tags: iphone, image, text, label, scrollview

I would like to add a page number above the image such as "1 of 50" and description of the image below the image in the scrollview.

I have looked at this [LINK](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Scrolling/Introduction/Intro.html) but still couldn't figure out how to make it happen.

here is my sample code of the images scrollview. Im trying to find a sample that can add text and scroll with the images

```
NSUInteger i;
        for (i = 1; i <= kNumImages; i++)
        {
                NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"images%d.jpg", i];
                UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
                UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

                // setup each frame to a default height and width, it will be properly placed when we call "updateScrollList"
                CGRect rect = imageView.frame;
                rect.size.height = kScrollObjHeight;
                rect.size.width = kScrollObjWidth;
                imageView.frame = rect;
                imageView.tag = i;  // tag our images for later use when we place them in serial fashion
                [scrollView1 addSubview:imageView];
                [imageView release];
        }
```

UPDATE:

```
const CGFloat kScrollObjHeight  = 320;
const CGFloat kScrollObjWidth   = 280.0;
const NSUInteger kNumImages     = 50;


- (void)layoutScrollImages
{
UIImageView *view = nil;
NSArray *subviews = [scrollView1 subviews];

// reposition all image subviews in a horizontal serial fashion
CGFloat curXLoc = 0;
for (view in subviews)
{
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]] && view.tag > 0)
        {
                CGRect frame = view.frame;
                frame.origin = CGPointMake(curXLoc, 0);
                view.frame = frame;

                curXLoc += (kScrollObjWidth);
        }
}
- (void)viewDidLoad {

        self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor viewFlipsideBackgroundColor];

        // 1. setup the scrollview for multiple images and add it to the view controller
        //
        // note: the following can be done in Interface Builder, but we show this in code for clarity
        [scrollView1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        [scrollView1 setCanCancelContentTouches:NO];
        scrollView1.indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite;
        scrollView1.clipsToBounds = YES;        // default is NO, we want to restrict drawing within our scrollview
        scrollView1.scrollEnabled = YES;

        // pagingEnabled property default is NO, if set the scroller will stop or snap at each photo
        // if you want free-flowing scroll, don't set this property.
        scrollView1.pagingEnabled = YES;

        // load all the images from our bundle and add them to the scroll view
        NSUInteger i;
        for (i = 1; i <= kNumImages; i++)
        {
                NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"creative%d.jpg", i];
                UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
                UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

                // setup each frame to a default height and width, it will be properly placed when we call "updateScrollList"
                CGRect rect = imageView.frame;
                rect.size.height = kScrollObjHeight;
                rect.size.width = kScrollObjWidth;
                imageView.frame = rect;
                imageView.tag = i;  // tag our images for later use when we place them in serial fashion
                [scrollView1 addSubview:imageView];
                [imageView release];
        }

        [self layoutScrollImages];
```

I wanted to put this but unable to find the correct position or right offset to display at the top

```
UILabel * topLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
            topLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d of %d", i, kNumImages];
            rect.origin.x = offset;
            rect.size.height = 30; // however large you need the label to be
            topLabel.frame = rect;
            offset += 30;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think something like this would work:

```
    float offset = 0;
    for (NSUInteger i = 1; i <= kNumImages; i++)
    {
            // load up the image
            NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"images%d.jpg", i];
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
            UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

            // image.size is important here and used to determine placement
            CGRect rect = imageView.frame;
            rect.size = image.size;

            // create top label, just basic will need to configure other settings like font
            UILabel * topLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
            topLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d of %d", i, kNumImages];
            rect.origin.x = offset;
            rect.size.height = 30; // however large you need the label to be
            topLabel.frame = rect;
            offset += 30; // adding the label height

            // set image frame since we now know the location below top label            
            rect.size = image.size;
            rect.origin.x += offset;
            imageView.frame = rect;
            imageView.tag = i;
            offset += image.size.height; // adding image height

            // add bottom label below image
            UILabel * bottomLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
            bottomLabel.text = imageName; // just a sample description
            rect.origin.x += offset;
            rect.size.height = 30; // however large you need the label to be
            bottomLabel.frame = rect;
            offset += 30; // adding the label height

            [scrollView1 addSubview:topLabel];
            [scrollView1 addSubview:imageView];
            [scrollView1 addSubview:bottomLabel];
            [imageView release];
            [topLabel release];
            [bottomLabel release];

            offset += 20; // arbitrary spacing between images
    }
```

Comment: Before I try that, is there a way i can make a description diff. for each images? or better yet is it better if its better no loop and slide diff. images(diff. name file) with description link to the image? im still trying to find sample for that and which would be better easier way...

Comment: can i see sample of offset that is undeclared? and also can i see the sample of the topLabel.text = (samples of the description)
thanks!

Comment: @merril Not sure what you mean in your first comment, this builds a vertical list of the images with descriptions, you can do the same horizontally by using the offset as your Y axis instead of X axis.
Also offset starts at 0, you can set that up how you desire.
And topLabel is your "x of x" text, description you'll have to come up with as I see nothing mentioning what that may be.
Could just put `bottomLabel.text = imageName` (Aha just saw a copy-paste error, will fix it.)

Comment: the images are in loop which i have to rename all my image files to image1, image2, etc. I can do the same for page number but the description text(bottomlabel) how can I make it diff. description for each image without using a loop. By the way which ones have you fixed? THANKS!

Comment: I found out it was the wrong link i posted up i just updated and change the link that i was actually referring to.

Comment: I have a default size of image/scroll which i am going to post up in my updated post as i need to find a way to put the correct position of the text label.